# Zoomable map with markers in HTML5 using svg image

Tags: html, css, svg

I am creating a website that has a small map of a part of a town. 
The map should have markers (icons) that mark the most important attractions and it should have zoom in/out capabilities. It also has to cover the full page (responsive, depending on the resolution).

What i have right now:

I used a div with the .svg image set as background. Icons are absolute positioned small divs that are set to needed places using margins.

Now the problem is that when someone resizes the page or views the page in some other resolution, the markers move and don't show the needed location anymore.

How can I set them fixed to the div, so when the div is resized the icons stay in the needed place on the map? Also how to make the background image zoom in?

Comment: not sure if this is relivent, but you can imbed working sections of google maps, which has built in zoom functions.  Not sure if you could then add markers to this.

Comment: @SamDenton I have thought about using google maps, but it doesn't match the website style and doesn't really have the functionality I need. (filtering markers on click, show certain info on hover etc.)

Comment: have you looked into any pluggins? I am sure somone has one that sutes your needs

Comment: Put the markers in the svg and change your code to hide/show them to operate on the svg DOM

Comment: @KevinBrown if I put the markers in SVG, is it possible to pop out tooltips on hover and tie them with css?

Comment: You use an a element in svg just like you would in html